# Data table not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have a table which I populate using data from MySQL via PHP.

```
<table id="tab" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>           
          <th>Heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <?php
        session_start(); 
        $id=$_SESSION['id'];
        $val=$_SESSION['val'];

        if($val=="1")
        {
            $result = $obj->getAllVals();
        }
        else
        {
            $result = $obj->getVal($id);
        }

        foreach($result as $row) { ?>
                <tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick="gp('<?php echo $row['name']; ?>')">
                <td> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td> </tr>
            <?php }     ?>
      </tbody>

    </table>
```

I'm not able to see my data as a datatable. Here is how I'm calling Data tables:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tab').dataTable();
});
```

Here are the scripts I'm using:

```
<script src="static/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/lib/jquery.dataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/lib/jquery.dataTables/js/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/lib/jquery.dataTables/js/datatables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: And what are the errors you are getting.

Comment: check console for errors

Comment: I can not see the $obj object - can you post full code ?

Comment: the obj object is being called outside this snippet and the data from the database is being rendered as desired so the problem is not over there. The console is not throwing up any data table related errors.

Comment: Your script, say called /index.php, and js are in /static/js/jquery.js, ... you have a good relative path?

Comment: @Paulie Hi.. better you use proper server side technique as mentioned in data table [server side processing](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: does the php loop actualy have any data? what is the html source after you run this? are there any <tr> in the table? if not then there is a ptoblem with your php and not datatables

Comment: try to remove datatables.responsive.js,DT_bootstrap.js and try

Answer (score 3):

Are you sur the variable $result is populated?

What if you replace this:

> ```
>    foreach($result as $row) { ?>
>            <tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick="gp('<?php echo $row['name']; ?>')">
>            <td> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td> </tr>
>        <?php }     ?>
> ```

By this :

> ```
>    foreach($result as $row) { ?>
>            <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
>        <?php }     ?>
> ```

Does it shows a lot of "Test" cells?
If yes, then there is something wrong with getting the infos out of the "$row" variable.
If not, then there is something wrong with either the foreach loop, or with the "$obj->" calls.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least one error, that is outside the

```
<?php ?>
```

body:

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick="gp(\''.$row['name'].'\')">
```

=>

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick="gp('<?php echo $row['name']; ?>')">
```

Comment: ah that was am error! but the data table still isn't coming up.

Answer (score 1):

session start methode should be in first line of php file
 kindly  write

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a while loop, instead a foreach.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

          echo "<tr style='cursor:pointer' onclick='gp('".$row['name']."')'>
                    <td> ".$row['name']." </td> 
                </tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there are rows in the table and as you say "The console is not throwing up any data table related errors"

in that case you may want to check the non-related errors.
if there is an error it may stop all further script execution.

you should check if this line `$('#tab').dataTable();` is executed at all (you can just replace it with alert and see)

and if this is the case the problem will be solved by correcting thous errors